# Error 99 while using redislite with my flask application

Tags: python, redis, flask-caching

In my flask application I use a docker redis container (through flask caching), so I have specified the necessary parameters in the config file.

For some tests though I am using redislite and I delete the `HOST` and `PORT` from the config file. So I expect that the application will try to connect to the redislite socket. However, I get this message:

```
Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that in the config file the `CACHE_TYPE` was still `RedisCache`, while it should be `NullCache`.